# Dynamic text boxes with dropdown list

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm making a quiz system, base on value selected of dropdown list I can show a number of text boxes.
Example: Subject have 4 unit, I will have 4 text boxes to fill a number of questions for each unit.
My code not working:
Controller:

```
public function getunit($id){
    $units= Question::groupBy('unit')->select('unit', Question::raw('count(id) as Total'))->where('id_subject','=', $id)->get()->toArray();
    return view('Test::test', compact('units'));
}
```

Blade file:

```
$('select').select();
function get_units() {
    var id = $('#selectID').val();
    var list = $('#list-unit');
    list.empty();
    var url = "{{ route('test.getunit') }}"+'/'+id;
    var success = function (result) {
        if (result.length <= 0) {
            var item = '<div class="input-field"><input type="text" disabled value="Môn này hiện chưa có câu hỏi nào"></div>';
            list.append(item);
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var item = '<div class="input-field"><label for="unit-' + result[i].unit+ '">Nhập số câu hỏi chương ' + result[i].unit+ ' (có ' + result[i].Total + ' câu) <span class="failed">(*)</span></label><input type="number" max="' + result[i].Total + '" class="unit_input" onchange="set_sum(' + result[i].Total + ')"  name="unit-' + result[i].unit+ '" id="unit-' + result[i].unit+ '" required></div>';
                list.append(item);
            }
        }
    };
    $.get(url, success);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('get-unit', 'TestController@getunit')->name('test.getunit');

Route::resource('test', TestController::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to create textbox dynamically

let html="";

$.each([ "value1", ["value2","value3","value4"] ], function( index1, value1 )
{

html+="";

$.each(value1, function(index2, value2)
{

add text box here

});
html+="";

list.append(html);